# Find border-color for all <li>

Tags: javascript, styles, element

I'm sorry about that, i just began JS, and actually i don't understand something

I would like to find all color of my li border's

HTML:

```
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-images"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
```

SCSS :

```
  li {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      border-right: 6px solid #2196F3;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      border-right: 6px solid #00BCD4;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      border-right: 6px solid #4CAF50;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      border-right: 6px solid #FFC107;
    }
    &:nth-child(5) {
      border-right: 6px solid #FF5722;
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    a {
      color: $white;
      line-height: 20vh;
    }
  }
```

I tried this, but i got undefined

```
let icons = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(icons.style.borderColor);
```

Sorry for this noob question. Thanks for help !
Have a good day :)

Comment: You want a `for-loop`. Because you have a `set` of `elements`. To try what I mean check `console.log(icons[0].style.borderColor`.

Comment: I got an empty :(

Comment: The `style` attribute only has the values defined in the markup and not the computed styles from an included stylesheet or a `<style>` section. You will have to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Sorry. That is the other thing. With `.style` you only get the `inline-style`. You want `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelectorAll('li')[0]).getPropertyValue('border-color')`.

Comment: Oh yeah, ok i understand. Thanks ! Now i have to loop on all li to find all color. I'm gonna try. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are getting list of elements in your `icons` variable. You have to loop through it to find the border colour of each element.

```
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('li');
icons.forEach(function(i) {
   console.log(i)
   console.log(i.style['background-color']);
});
```

Comment: God bless you ! Thank you so much